# Cannot find the Umbraco route definition in the route values

Tags: c#, razor, umbraco

I'm trying to do something fairly basic, but it does not seem to work.
I have a razor page where I call an action 'Index' in my NewsSurfaceController.

```html
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
    Layout = "Master.cshtml";
}
<div class="row">
    <h1 class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">@CurrentPage.Name</h1>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-4 ">
        @Html.ActionLink("Archief", "Archive", "NewsSurface", null, new { @class = "content-link-button-reverse" })
    </div>
</div>



@Html.Action("Index", "NewsSurface")
```

My newscontroller:

```
public class NewsSurfaceController : SurfaceController
{
    private int itemsPerpage= 4;

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return PartialView("newslist", new NewsRepo(CurrentPage).items.Take(itemsPerpage));
    }

    public ActionResult Archive()
    {
       return PartialView("newslist", new NewsRepo(CurrentPage).archivedItems.Take(itemsPerpage));
    }

}
```

This returns a partial view that just iterates over the items.

```js
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<MyProject.models.NewsItemViewModel>


        @foreach (MyProject.models.NewsItem item in Model)
        {
            //displays the properties
        }
```

When I go to the page, it shows me the items correctly, but when I click on the actionlink it throws an error.

> Cannot find the Umbraco route definition in the route values, the request must be made in the context of an Umbraco request

When I debug, the problem seems to be the 'CurrentPage' object.

> at Umbraco.Web.Mvc.SurfaceController.get_CurrentPage()
>      at MyProject.Controllers.NewsSurfaceController.Archive() in C:\Users\thomas\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MyProject\Controllers\NewsSurfaceController.cs:line 25
>      at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()

What am I doing wrong?
Could anyone point me in the right direction.

Kind regards!

---------Edit--------

Ok Apparently this is a bug in Umbraco.
[Issue on the umbraco forum](http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-8357)

Answer (score 0):

Is your controller inheriting from SurfaceController? If not, the route won't be registered for you.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I'm sorry for the confusion, I should have put my complete controller code in my post. It is inheriting from SurfaceController.